# Amazon Interview Maximum Number of People present at an Event at any time

Tags: algorithm

Assume I have a list of people with their arrival and departure time at an event that happened in the past.

My task is to find out the **maximum number of people** present in the event at **any time**? I am not given query time.

ai = Arrival time of person i

di = Departure time of person i

I have a list of pairs like (a1,d1), (a2,d2), (a3,d3).... (an,dn)... 
It's not in a database.

[image]

In this problem we can see that the maximum number of people at the event is 3.
So in this eg. we have five solutions to the problem with size 3. **{b,d,e}, {j,h,i}, {c,b,a}, {e,g,f}, {g,h,f}** . 
I just want to know the number 3.

My Approaches:
i. Create an array of size = Last Departure Time - First arrival time. And keep incrementing the count of that array.
 ii.  I tried to sort the people by their start times. And keep jumping to
    the start time of the next person. After that I am lost. How should
    I proceed.

Thanks

@ypnos :
//Sorted the data both on timestamps.

```
int count = 0;
int max = 0
char [] arr = {a1, a2, d1, a3, a4, d3, d2, } like this..
for(int i =0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    if(arr[i].startswith('a') ) 
    {
         count++;
    if(count > max)
    {
        max = count;
    }
    }
    else
   {
    count--;
   }
}
```

Comment: A segment tree (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) can solve this problem, but you may not be interested in implementing one...

Comment: By the way, the title says "Maximum" but the question doesn't mention that - are you interested in a general query or only in the maximum?

Comment: Even with your clarification, the answer wouldn't be difficult if you sort your data by arrival time. Of course, it depends on how your code is called.

Comment: I am just interested in the Maximum people at the event at any time.

Comment: Speaking of code, is there any? The language that you choose to write this in is going to drastically impact the answer (such as what libraries/object types are available - NumPy, etc.)

Comment: I am interested in the approach. It need not be language specific.

Comment: My point is that any optimized approach will be language specific due to the different object types/libraries that may/may not be available. I don't see how a solid answer could come from this question, other than just looping a dictionary/hash/associative array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you create a sorted list with arrival and departure times. It is a **single** list for **both** events, and each event consists of a timestamp (what is the sorting key) and a boolean (arrival or departure).

**New solution (find the maximum):**

Then you can iterate through your list, remember the current number at each entry and increment/decrement it accordingly, while also updating your maximum number if appropriate.

Sorting: O(N log N), finding the max. number: O(N)

**Old solution due to bad wording in the question (query at time X):**

After you have that list, you create a map that has timestamps as keys and the number of people at that current timestamp as data. To create that, you go through your sorted list, remember the current number at each entry and increment/decrement it accordingly, while also adding the element to your map.

Now that you have the map, you can trivially find the right number by searching for the element in the map left of your query timestamp.

With a map I mean a binary tree, or what is the base of std::map. Btw. std::map provides you with the lower_bound() function to do that ([ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/lower_bound/)).

However, it is not hard to implement a binary tree yourself. Now for the costs of the operation: O(log N) per entry, O(log N) per query.

Comment: How do I keep increment/decrement it. I need to scan through the entire list to find out if it is still colliding or not.

Comment: No, the idea is that you have a list of increment events and decrement events. You don't care _which_ person is departing, only that anybody is departing. That's why you go from  (a1,d1), (a2,d2), (a3,d3).... (an,dn) to (a1, d1, a2, d2, a3, d3, .., an, dn). Then you sort that array according to timestamps, so you will get sth like a1, a2, d1, a3, a4, d3, d2, ... and so on.

Comment: Supercool Idea. Thanks so much. Finally somebody was able to understand my question and nail the solution :) :)
Just to clarify, you are saying the following :       

int count = 0;
int max = 0
char [] arr = {a1, a2, d1, a3, a4, d3, d2, } like this..
for(int i =0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    if(arr[i].startswith('a') ) 
    {
         count++;
 if(count > max)
 {
  max = count;
 }
    }
   {
 count--;
   }
}

Comment: I have written the code above in the question. It would be great if you could please have a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in a database?  If so, you just select the rows with arrival time < now < departure time.

This is a simple thing to do, but we need to know what data structure you are using to hold the data to give a specific solution.

The approach is simple:  An array of dictionaries where each dictionary consists of arrival:value and departure:value.  Then at any given time, you iterate the array and if:
    arrival < now < departure == TRUE you increment a counter.

Done.

Comment: No. This is not stored in a database. I have updated the question. Please have a look at it once again. Thanks .

Comment: @HackyStack: Why have an array of dictionaries? He already has a list of pairs as input, which is exactly the same. Your solution has complexity of O(n) for each query, but the optimal solution is O(log N) for each query.

Comment: @HackyStack: I don't have any query time. I have rephrased the question once again with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the list, test if the given time `t` is between arrival and departure of the current pair and increment a counter if that is the case. Afterwards you should have the correct number in your counter. Pseudocode:

```
given time T
given list of (arrival, departure) pairs L

c = 0
for each pair (A, D) in L
    if A < T and T < D
        c += 1
```

Note that this is not the most optimal solution... storing your data in a structure more suitable for querying will enable more efficient solutions.

Comment: Over here, I assume that you are claiming that you know the time T. But we don't know that.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL?

```
SELECT count(id) FROM attendee WHERE a_time < '2013-03-01 12:12' AND (d_time > '2013-03-01 12:12' OR d_time IS NULL)
```